# Terrraform Snowflake create table : Preserve column order when adding new columns

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I manage snowflake tables via Terraform.

I would like to preserve columns order when i add a new column in an existing table. Default terraform behavior is to append new columns at the of the DDL create table expression.

As an example :  I first create a table

```
resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
  database            = snowflake_schema.schema.database
  schema              = snowflake_schema.schema.name
  name                = "table"

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "int"
  }

  column {
    name     = "identity"
    type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
  }

  column {
    name     = "final"
    type     = " VARCHAR(100)"
  }
}
```

terraform gives me the following DDL expression.

```sql
create or replace TABLE table (
    "id" int,
"identity" NUMBER(38,0),
"final" VARCHAR(100) )
```

If i want to add a new column, i modify the terraform script to something like:

```
resource "snowflake_table" "table" {
  database            = snowflake_schema.schema.database
  schema              = snowflake_schema.schema.name
  name                = "table"

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "int"
  }

  column {
    name     = "test"
    type     = " VARCHAR(100)"
  }

  column {
    name     = "identity"
    type     = "NUMBER(38,0)"
  }

  column {
    name     = "final"
    type     = "VARCHAR(100)"
  }
}
```

I want the test column to be in second position.

But Terraform generates the DDL expression

```sql
create or replace TABLE table (
"id" int,
"identity" NUMBER(38,0) ,
"final" VARCHAR(100),
"test" VARCHAR(100) )
```

As the table is already in place

But I need :

```sql
create or replace TABLE table (
"id" int,
"identity" NUMBER(38,0) ,
"test" VARCHAR(100),
"final" VARCHAR(100))
```

I have some code generated sql statements the depend on the column order and i would like the sql column order to be the same as the csv files they are coming from.

Currently I have to destroy the table resource to create a new one. I would like to know if there is a way to change the appending default behavior ?

Comment: You probably need to raise this as a request on the Snowflake provider tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does not support specifying the position of the added column. This is why Terraform can not add the column in the middle.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction

Comment: Thank you Gokhan.  It's clear it cannot be done via an ALTER command.  I'm looking for a way  (some option) to force (re)creation of the table and not an append like the default snowflake provide terraform behavior.